# How to make SUMIF only consider the first column of a range?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet with 11 columns (A to K).  I want a SUMIF to look at column A and add up the values in column K so my range is A-to-K.  However, there are figures in columns B through J that match by criteria, and SUMIF then counts those in the total.  How do I make SUMIF only consider column A?

Example:

```
   Column A      Column B     Column K
1  Dog           Snake        8
2  Dog           Bird         16
3  Cat           Dog          32
4  Cat           Lizard       64
5  Dog           Banana       128
```

I want my SUMIF look up "dog" in column A, then only add K1, K2 and K5.  However I am also getting K3 right now.

Comment: What does your sumif look like?

Comment: =SUMIF(A:K,R5,K:K)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=SUMIF(A1:A5, "dog", K1:K5)
```

will look up "dog" in Column `A`, then add the corresponding values in Column `K`.